# Anmimation on 2 views in fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(
  R.animator.1, R.animator.2,R.animator.3, R.animator.4)
  .replace(view1, view2)
  .addToBackStack(null)
  .commit();
```

This only performs animation on **view2**. I also want to do something with **view1** at the same time. how can I do that? These views are FrameLayouts with dynamic generated id

Answer (score 2):

Refering to android developers: 
 [FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

If I clearly understand what you need, for using animation for 1 view you must provide animator for exit parameter

Comment: it seems my R.animator.2 and R.animator.4 wont work on view1. no matter what I do in the animator files it just wont change view1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself. The manager was stacking my transaction before I set the animation, so it stacks the transaction without animations (sad but true), and that occurs even with if I commit the transaction after the setCustom() method.

The solution is to set the animations first:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();       
transaction.setCustomAnimations(view1,view2);
transaction.replace(R.id.content, myFragment);
transaction.commit();
```